# How to use joblib.Parallel() to parallelize a loop with some "continue" in it?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

Let's say I have a loop that "outputs" only if some condition is met :

```
output = []
for item in some_list:
    if condition(item):
        res = do_something(item)
        output.append(res)
```

For memory constraints I can't fill the `output` list with `None`-s, so I can't write :

```
joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=n)(joblib.delayed(do_something)(item) for item in some_list)
```

Is there a fast and reasonable way to make the list of outputs generated by `Parallel` not to include the redundant `None`-s?

EDIT

I forgot to clarify that both checking `condition(item)` and the actual `do_something(item)` take too long in aggregate so I'm trying to parallelize both.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Is there a fast and reasonable way to make the list of outputs generated by `Parallel` not to include the redundant `None`-s?"*

Yes.

Define the `for item`-generator part as needed :

```
joblib.Parallel( n_jobs = n )( joblib.delayed( do_something )( item )
                                                           for item in some_list
                                                 if condition( item )
                               )
```

Comment: oh, now I see that I should have been clearer in my question. the thing is that both `do_something` and `condition` take too much time without parallelization